# Leer correctamente Struct desde un archivo binario con ifstream

Tags: c++, binary-files

en esta ocasión quisiera pedirles su ayuda en como hacer `.push_back` o imprimir el valor del elemento del struct con `cout`, al momento de leer los datos desde un archivo binario, he logrado almacenar la información correctamente, y el ciclo `while` recorre efectivamente los 3 registros que se han almacenado, pero al momento de querer hacer `.push_back` a el `vector<Student>` simplemente el programa no lo realiza y algo que no entiendo, es porque no termina con el return 0, se queda como colgando y termina como a la fuerza, pero sin mostrar ningún error, estoy utilizando Dev C++, les dejo el código completo para que puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias de antemano.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Estudiante {
    int id;
    string nombre;
};

int main() {
  //vector que almacena todo
  vector<Estudiante> estudiantes;

  //estructura temporal
  Estudiante new_estudiante;
  //llenando el struct
  new_estudiante.id = 1;
  new_estudiante.nombre = "Nombre1";
  estudiantes.push_back(new_estudiante);

  new_estudiante.id = 2;
  new_estudiante.nombre = "Nombre2";
  estudiantes.push_back(new_estudiante);

  new_estudiante.id = 3;
  new_estudiante.nombre = "Nombre3";
  estudiantes.push_back(new_estudiante);

  //escribiendo el archivo
  ofstream escritor("estudiantes.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);
  if(!escritor) {
    cout << "Error al abrir el archivo estudiantes.dat" << endl;
    return 1;
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < estudiantes.size(); i++){
    escritor.write((char *) &estudiantes.at(i), sizeof(Estudiante));
  }
  escritor.close();

  //limpiando el vector inicial, pues se llenara con el codigo que sigue
  estudiantes.clear();

  //recuperando los datos
  ifstream lector("estudiantes.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);
  if(!lector) {
    cout << "Error al abrir el archivo estudiantes.dat" << endl;
    return 1;
  }

  Estudiante estudiante_temp;
  while(lector.read((char*) &estudiante_temp,sizeof(Estudiante))){
    cout << "i" << endl; //compruebo cuantas veces se repite el read
    //estudiantes.push_back(estudiante_temp); //Aqui deberia ser tan simple como realizar esto, pero no...
  }

  //mostrando los datos
  cout<<"Estudiantes (" << estudiantes.size() << "):"<<endl;
  for(int i=0; i < estudiantes.size(); i++) {
    cout << "{";
    cout << "id: " << estudiantes.at(i).id;
    cout << "nombre: " << estudiantes.at(i).nombre;
    cout << "}" << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: A la hora de ejecutarlo, lo haces en modo debug? Sería bueno que lo hagas en ese modo. Te dará más información de hasta donde funciona bien el código.

Comment: Por cierto, para ifstream deberías usar `ios::in` porque estás leyendo los datos, no escribiéndolos

Comment: Hiceel cambio de `ios::in` e de igual manera pasa lo mismo, pero hare la modificacion en la pregunta

Comment: Se me ocurre que tal vez el problema sea cuando lees varios elementos en lugar de uno solo. Intenta leer solo un estudiante y dime si te da error

Comment: En teoria en el while, cada vez que se repite, solo esta leyendo 1 estudiante, o estoy leyendo varios elementos sin darme cuenta?